# Unable to compile CUDA C sources. Simple version is provided

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvcc

Here is the problem...
For school project I need to write parallel application using CUDA C. Even the most simple example will not compile. I'm using Windows7 and MS visual studio. The code is taken from the book: CUDA by example. An introduction to general purpose GPU computing.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cuda.h>

using namespace std;

__global__ void kernel(void){
}

int main(){
kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
cout << "Hello world" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
1>c:\users\administrator\documents\visualstudio2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(6): error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'
1>c:\users\administrator\documents\visualstudio2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(6): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\administrator\documents\visualstudio2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(10): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
```

Do I need to set nvcc.exe as default compiler instead of cl.exe? If that is the case, how to do it?
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CUDA code needs to be written in a `.cu` file and compiled with the **NVCC** compiler. You are seeing the above errors because you have written your code in a `.c` or `.cpp` file and are trying to compile it with a C++ compiler (the Visual C++ compiler).

You have chosen the right book to learn CUDA from. However, you are not following all the steps given in the book. Please have a look at the details of compilation in the book :-)

Comment: Thanks... After renaming test.cpp to test.cu CUDA C did compile the code but I thought it would create test.exe file not a.exe! It looks like I've been searching the wrong .exe! -_- Thank you Ashwin for the reply.

Comment: You can specify the name of the resulting executable with NVCC, if your CUDA source code is named *file.cu* and you want the resulting file to be named *file.exe* try with this command *nvcc file.cu -o file.exe*. Hope this will help.

Comment: @mmisu Yes... That helped. Thank you for the info! I probably should have read nvcc manual before posting a question. Well, it's never too late, I hope!